# Eclipse Java debug perspective: pause not showing which line halted at

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I want to do some very simple profiling: by running my Java application using the Debug command, then pausing to see what line in the source it was halted at. I open the debug perspective, run the menu option `Run > Debug` and then hit the pause button. I would expect the IDE to show which line in the source that the application has been halted at, but I can't see any indication. How can I achieve this?

Here is the debugging window screenshot while paused:

[image]

Comment: A screenshot would probably help. But in general you have to navigate through the list of threads to find their current position. It's a lot easier to simply put a breakpoint where you want to trace the code from.

Comment: Thanks - I'm not sure what I should take a screen shot of exactly? A breakpoint defeats the object; I want a quick-and-dirty way of finding bits of code that the application spends most of its time in, which pausing during execution several times should do.

Comment: Can you drill down further into each of those threads (i.e. click the triangle on their right)?  If they are paused in class files that were not compiled with debug lines turned on, then I think you won't see the line numbers.

Comment: @Jodes I see, I was going to say that's the only real reason not to use breakpoints. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to expand those individual threads on your screenshot, revealing the current stack trace of that particular thread. Of course finding which thread you want can often be tricky, in this particular case I suspect it's the AWT EventQueue or the TimerQueue threads that are doing most of the work.

But it really isn't much more effort to launch [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) and start CPU sampling, which is basically an automated way of doing what you do here.